# Unable to read an uploaded multipart xml file

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am trying to write a service that receives a xml file and parses it and does some additional processing.
At the UI controller I converted the multipart file contents to a string and passed it to the service.
  From the UI controller - I upload the file and call the service method to parse the xml file

```
 MultipartFile newFile=multiPartRequest.getFile("newFileUpload");
 String fileContent = new String(newFile.getBytes());
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
 InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(fileContent));
 doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
```

However, doc is always null. What is the best way for me to rest this xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its a problem with the

```
String fileContent  String fileContent = new String(newFile.getBytes());
```

Since not all the bytes of the file are just text , you have the header and eof and bytes that don't represent a text .

What you should do is make a InputStream and build the document off that , like so :

```
   try{    
        MultipartFile newFile=multiPartRequest.getFile("newFileUpload");
        InputStream is = new newFile.getInputStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();                 
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
      } catch (SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication4.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```